# any method to wait until invisible progressbar in espresso test?

Tags: android-espresso

Eg. I have created two activities and second activities contain recycler item list and progress bar. until finish API call we are waiting for a response and shows progress bar

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Hey and welcome to StackOverflow! What kind of a progress bar do you have? If you could share the code of it that would be excellent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to wait until your ProgressBar is hidden.
You can either create an `idling resource` or use a custom ViewAction as this one:

```
/**
 * Perform action of waiting until the element is accessible & not shown.
 * @param viewId The id of the view to wait for.
 * @param millis The timeout of until when to wait for.
 */
public static ViewAction waitUntilNotShown(final int viewId, final long millis) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isRoot();
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "wait for a specific view with id <" + viewId + "> is hidden during " + millis + " millis.";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(final UiController uiController, final View view) {
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
            final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long endTime = startTime + millis;
            final Matcher<View> viewMatcher = withId(viewId);

            do {
                for (View child : TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(view)) {
                    // found view with required ID
                    if (viewMatcher.matches(child) && !child.isShown()) {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(50);
            }
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime);

            // timeout happens
            throw new PerformException.Builder()
                    .withActionDescription(this.getDescription())
                    .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
                    .withCause(new TimeoutException())
                    .build();
        }
    };
}
```

And you can use it this way:

```
onView(isRoot()).perform(waitUntilNotShown(R.id.theIdToWaitFor, 5000));
```

changing `theIdToWaitFor` with the specific id of your `ProgressBar` and updating the timeout of 5 secs (5000 millis) if necessary.

However, depending on which test you are doing, if this is not an integration test it's better not to make real api calls.

Answer (score 1):

//I use this simple code (no IdlingResource os custom matcher). Where viewId is the view you want to verify once ProgressBar is gone

```
fun viewIsDisplayedAfterProgressDialogIsGone(viewId: Int){
    onView(withId(viewId))
        .inRoot(not(RootMatchers.isDialog()))
        .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an adapted version of [jeprubio's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59015466/3692788).

```
/**
 * Wait until the element is accessible and not shown.
 * @param millis The maximum timeout to wait for.
 */
fun waitUntilNotShown(millis: Long): ViewAction {
    return object : ViewAction {
        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
            return any(View::class.java)
        }

        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return "Wait for a specific view to be hidden, for a max of $millis ms."
        }

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle()

            val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val endTime = startTime + millis

            do {
                if (!view.isShown) {
                    return
                }
                uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(100)
            } while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime)

            throw PerformException.Builder()
                .withActionDescription(this.description)
                .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
                .withCause(TimeoutException())
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can use this way:

```
onView(withId(R.id.welcome_progress_bar))
  .perform(waitUntilNotShown(3_000))
```

I made this change since I was getting errors when using `onView(isRoot())`.